# Divide object of type Integer and Double

Tags: java

I want to divide a number by 100 and number is of Object type.

```
Object a = 33;
Object b = .33;


Double d = (Double) a / 100;
Double e = (Double) b / 100;
```

First, I had type cast to Double, but it's failing "Cannot cast numeric value to java.lang.Double" for Integer.

Do I need to check instance before dividing? I am new and not sure what is correct way to do it?

**EDIT:** I cannot avoid Object

Comment: Don't use wrapper types when you're doing math. Use `double`, not `Double`.

Comment: Also avoid using `Object` when dealing with numeric wrappers whenever possible. You'll run into more problems with that than you're willing to solve.

Comment: I cannot avoid Object since it's already used for multiple data types. Any explanation of down votes? Should I delete this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you must use objects (and I suggest you don't for a number of reasons) you could do this

```
Number a = 33;
Number b = 0.33;

Number d = a.doubleValue() / 100.0;
Number e = b.doubleValue() / 100.0;
```

However, you should really only use objects for numbers if

- the value could be `null`
- you are using it as a generic type e.g. `List<Double>`
- you are using a type which doesn't have a primitive e.g. `BigDecimal`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use doubles not Objects

```
    final int a = 33;
    final double b = 0.33;
    final double d = a / 100.0;
    final Double e = b / 100.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java you can cast primitives like **int** to a **double** but you can't do the same with the wrapper classes like **Integer** and **Double**.

In your example, 33 is autoboxed to an Integer, which cannot then be cast to a Double. In the specific case you can avoid the exception by the following way:

```
    Object a = 33;

    if(a instanceof Number) {
        Double d = ((Number) a).doubleValue() / 100;
        System.out.println(d);
    }
```

But there is not the best way to solve you problem. Better to use primitive int and double, or theirs wrappers Integer and Double, but not Object.